# Why all supersingular elliptic curves over $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ are isogenous?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, isogeny

Lemma 3.2.1 in [Baker, González-Jiménez, González, Poonen, "Finiteness theorems for modular curves of genus at least 2", Amer. J. Math. 127 (2005), 1325–1387.](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/finiteness.pdf) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecXLP.png)
I don't understand why "all supersingular elliptic curves over $\bar{F_p}$ are isogenous".
Could anyone help me?
This problem arises from [Supersingular elliptic curves and their "functorial" structure over F_p^2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18982/supersingular-elliptic-curves-and-their-functorial-structure-over-f-p2).
Moreover, I found some similar question: [Isogenies between elliptic curves and their endomorphism rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364125/isogenies-between-elliptic-curves-and-their-endomorphism-rings) and [Isogenies between supersingular elliptic curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86444/isogenies-between-supersingular-elliptic-curves).

Comment: One way to prove this is to show that the rational Dieudonne module of a supersingular elliptic curve has to be an isocrystal of the form (depending on how you normalize things) $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ p & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and then use Tate's isogeny theorem.

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444846/why-all-supersingular-elliptic-curves-over-bar-mathbbf-p-are-isogenous)

Comment: (Now answered on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444846/why-all-supersingular-elliptic-curves-over-bar-mathbbf-p-are-isogenous)